# How can I hide element by class in wkwebview in swift ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, hide, wkwebview

I have to hide element using javascript in swift. In which file i need do do changes??
I have tried multiple options but nothing worked until now. I want to hide google sign-in option on web view.

**Code for reference**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import JavaScriptCore



class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate,WKUIDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate{
    
     var webView: WKWebView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        load remote url
        //let url = URL(string: "https://www.true-elements.com/")!
        //webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: "https://www.true-elements.com/")!))
        
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementByClassName(\"webview-d-none\").style.display='none';", completionHandler: { (res, error) -> Void in
                //Here you can check for results if needed (res) or whether the execution was successful (error)
            })
        
        
//        load local html file
//        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "local_html")!
//        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
//        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
//        webView.load(request)
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
        /*let tscript = " document.getElementsByClassName('webview-d-none')[0].style.display = 'none';"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(tscript)*/
        
       // let jsString = "var script = document.getElementsByClassName('webview-d-none')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';"
        //    webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString)
        
       // webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('webview-d-none')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';")
        
        
        
    }
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you want to hide HTML elements, you need to do this inside of your html and js code.

Comment: @tomerpacific I did this in android webview app in similar way and it worked. therefore I was trying the same thing in swift webview. I also checked in the swift documentation , we can inject javascript code in swift.

Comment: Are you asking how to call javascript methods inside a webview from Swift? Please also add your html and js files.

Comment: @tomerpacific , yes i want to hide a element using inbuilt java script methods. I cannot add html and js files as I dont have control over website , i am app developer.

Comment: If you are not loading the html in the WKWebview, how do you expect to setup the communication bridge?